# Why is CH4 a gas at room temperature but CH3Cl a liquid?

Tags: bond, phase, boiling-point

I cannot figure out a question on my review sheet. The full question is:

> Methane ($\ce{CH4}$) is a gas at room temperature but chloroform ($\ce{CH3Cl}$) is a liquid. Explain why changing just one $\ce{H}$ atom for a $\ce{Cl}$ atom changes the compound's state at room temp.

I thought about it, and I think it does have to do with $\ce{CH4}$ is non polar, so it does not tend to stick to each other (gas state), while $\ce{CH3Cl}$ is polar, so it does stick, such as like $\ce{H2O}$, which is liquid and is cohesive, so $\ce{CH3Cl}$ would be as well. Is anyone able to tell me if I am on the right path?

Comment: see http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/6859/how-to-determine-whether-a-compound-is-gas-or-liquid-or-solid

Comment: The question itself if just wrong: chloromethane is not chloroform and chloromethane is not a liquid but a gas at room temperature. That's a pretty bad epic fail for a chemistry question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, I think that is the right answer expected for this question.

---

**Three factors to consider.**

(1) Most importantly there four intermolecular forces which effect BP

Ionic bonds  > Ion-dipole interactions > H bonding >  dipole-dipole interactions > Van der Waals dispersion forces.

(2) Increasing the number of carbon atoms (e.g. n-alkanes) increases the BP

(3) Branching on carbon chain lowers the BP.

---

The answer being given though is a bit of hand-waving that oversimplifies the situation. Dipole moment alone can't explain the overall trends. Van der Waals dispersion forces must be considered also.

For instance with increasing substitution $\ce{CH2Cl2}$, and $\ce{CHCl3}$ both have lower dipole moments than $\ce{CH3Cl}$ but higher BP's. $\ce{CCl4}$ has no dipole moment like methane, but has the highest BP of all.

```
                                          Bond Lengths
           Dipole     B.P.       Mol.
           Moment     (°C)       Wt.       C-H     C-X
 CH4         0        −161.49    16.04     108.7    ---
 CH3Cl       1.9       −23.8     50.49     111      178.3   
 CH2Cl2      1.6        39.6     84.93     106.8    177.2
 CHCl3       1.15       61.15    119.37    107.3    176.7  
 CCl4        0          76.72    153.81    -----    176.6
```

Also look at the halomethanes as a series. $\ce{CH3F}$ has a smaller dipole moment than $\ce{CH3Cl}$ because the bond length is shorter.

```
           Dipole   B.P      Mol.      Electro-  C-X     C-H
           Moment   (°C)     Wt.       Negat.    Length  Length
 CH3F       1.85    −78.4    34.03     4.0       138.5   109.5
 CH3Cl      1.87    −23.8    50.49     3.0       178.4   
 CH3Br      1.81      4.0    94.94     2.8       192.9
 CH3I       1.62      42     141.94    2.5       213.9
```

The trend for molecular weight looks good, but the deuterated form of methane, $\ce{CD4}$, has the same (or at least nearly the same) boiling point as $\ce{CH4}$.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to predict boiling points of the four substances would indeed be expected to be given as:

> $\ce{CH3Cl}$ is a dipole. The dipole-dipole interactions are much stronger than the van der Waals interactions present in methane, so it’s boiling point is much higher.
>
> When comparing $\ce{CH4}$ to $\ce{CCl4}$, the latter has a much higher boiling point due to its larger number of electrons meaning stronger van der Waals forces.

---

That said, **the teacher that gave you the above information should be removed from chemistry classes immediately.** Here’s why:

- $\ce{CH3Cl}$ is **not** chloroform but methyl chloride or chloromethane. It is a **gas** at room temperature with a boiling point $\vartheta_\mathrm{b} = - 23.8~\mathrm{^\circ C}$.
- Chloroform, which is indeed a liquid at room temperature ($\vartheta_\mathrm{b} = 61.2~\mathrm{^\circ C}$) is $\ce{CHCl3}$ or trichloromethane. You need to substitute *three* hydrogens with chlorine atoms to create chloroform.